# Setting QTMovie attributes

Tags: cocoa, macos, quicktime, qtkit

I'm trying to create a QTVR movie via QTKit, and I've got all the frames in the movie.  However, setting the attributes necessary doesn't seem to be having any effect.  For example:

```
NSNumber *val = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
[fMovie setAttribute:val forKey:QTMovieIsInteractiveAttribute];

val = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
[fMovie setAttribute:val forKey:QTMovieIsLinearAttribute];
```

If I then get the value of these attributes, they come up as NO and YES, respectively.  The movie is editable, so I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here.  How can I ensure that the attributes will actually change?

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I want to export a Quicktime movie is something like the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], QTMovieExport,
    [exportSettings objectForKey: @"subtype"], QTMovieExportType,
    [exportSettings objectForKey: @"manufacturer"], QTMovieExportManufacturer,
    [exportSettings objectForKey: @"settings"], QTMovieExportSettings,                                      
  nil];

BOOL didSucceed = [movie writeToFile: tmpFileName withAttributes:dictionary error: &error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Those attributes are documented as things you can read but not write.  However, you might be able to set them when you create the movie, with initWithAttributes:error:.